# c# AudioVideoPlayback how to avoid ActiveMovie Window

Tags: c#, video, popup, directx, audiovideoplayback

I try to play a video with DirectX in C# in a panel. This works well so far.
But, unfortunately, always when the video starts a window titled "ActiveMovie Window" pops up.
It goes away once the video is displayed in the panel.

How can I suppress this? Looks a bit odd, if a window pops up and then disappears
when the video starts.

Here is the code:

```
             Video m_Video = null;
             Panel m_Panel = new Panel();
             m_Panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
             m_Panel.Location = new Point(posx, posy);
             m_Video = Video.FromFile(link, true);
             m_Video.Owner = m_Panel;
             m_Panel.Size = new Size(x, y);
             m_Video.Size = new Size(x,y);
             m_Video.Fullscreen = false;
             m_Video.HideCursor();

             Controls.Add(m_Panel);
             m_Video.Play();
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/23308757/868014