# Activemovie window pop up Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback in C#

Tags: c#, video, directx, directshow, audiovideoplayback

I had create a simple windows form which display a video with Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback. When the video load to the panel, it pop up for milliseconds a activemovie window. How i could fix it because it is annoy every time start playing a video throws this activemovie window. It is like the application have delay.

Here is my code :

```
   string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Photos\test.avi");

   var ofd = path;
   var video = new Video(ofd, true);
   label3.Text = ofd;
   video.Owner = panel2;
   panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640,480);
   video.Ending += new EventHandler(videocountdown_Ending);
   video.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480);
```

[image]

Above it is a printscreen when i press the button which play the video. I crop it and i show you only the panel in this picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
video = new Video(ofd, true);
video.Owner = panel2;
```

So you auto-run it before binding to the panel? I suppose you want it the other way: create, then `Owner` thing, then `Play`.

```
video = new Video(ofd, false);
video.Owner = panel2;
video.Play();
```

Playback without UI initialization makes the video renderer to render video into private popup window, which has a historic caption ["ActiveMovie"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveMovie), which is soon to celebrate 20 year anniversary...

Comment: I correct it but i have the same problem.So how i could play a video with UI initialization without Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback. With right render and play without pop up activemovie window

Comment: I made a quick check and I see that it is helpful as expected. No popup window with proper early `Owner` initialization.

Comment: I had add the your lines but it still pop ups for milliseconds the activemovie window like the printscreen in my question above.

Comment: for the record - my code with two buttons [VideoPlayback01/Form1.cs](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/VideoPlayback01/Form1.cs) show it pretty clear, one buttons causes the popup blink, and the other makes it clean.

Comment: I create a new form and i copy and paste your code. When i clicked the buttons doesn't do anything. I had put my path with my video and it doesn't respond at both buttons.